# css how to increase the size of rounded image button with varying text

Tags: php, html, css

Can somebody please help me out on how to increase the size of the rounded button with respect to text. Please check the image:

[image]

I want to be able to write any length of text and rounded button will stretch automatically based on text.

Please help me on how to write CSS for to get this working ?

**Note:** I don't want to use CSS3 `border-radius` because it does not work in IE and I don't want to use css3pie, etc, that's why i have created the rounded images. Thanks

Comment: A `background-color` and a `border-radius` is definitely the easiest to do :)

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Comment: It's a technique called Sliding Doors.  
You can find a lot of tutorials googling this words.

Comment: Just the width or height as well?

Comment: I believe width alone is needed for the kind of question asked.

Comment: I agree with @jensgram - `border-raidus` is the best solution. Any reason why you don't want to use CSS3Pie for IE? It is very good. (if it's a specific issue with a bug in CSS3Pie, please report it, and if it can't be fixed, there are other similar tools available which can also do the job without resorting to old-skool image-based layouts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Sliding Door Principle. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/.

In sliding doors you have two extreme as images(rounded) between these images is a background. The images move (slide further) based on the length of the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
}
ul li {
    height: 31px; // height of the background image *reused below
    margin: 10px; // width of the left image *reused below
    float: left;
    background: url(left.png) no-repeat top left;
}
ul li div {
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: url(right.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

//used with

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><div>text</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div>texttexttext</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div>texttexttexttext</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did this example with the left image being the 'small' image, and the right image is larger than any one button you want to display

Comment: divs aren't allowed in anchor elements.

Comment: my bad, just use another element, this was meant as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably opt for creating a div which inherits a css class like the following

```
<div class="button">TEXT HERE</div>
```

The CSS would be the following:

```
.button { border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; background-color: blue; }
```

The above style would allow all browsers (except older IE's) to render the rounded corners rounded which means you will have no need for images

Comment: I would agree with you. But still you need to take care of IE. Since IE6 and IE7 are still widely used.

Comment: I think IE 7 could still be a concern but even Microsoft themselves have condemned IE6 to be depreciated as it is almost its 10th birthday. Even at that, the View and IE7 user gets will not be incorrect - just slightly different, more or less the same effect a font stack would take when a user doesn't have support for a font

Comment: The OP did specifically state that he didn't want to use `border-radius`, which is a shame because it is the best solution, and CSS3Pie (and other similar tools) mean that it can be made to work even in older versions of IE.